# Java adding code to a variable

Tags: java

I'm wondering if I can add code to an object variable and run it later?
I want to do something like this:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.addCode(
  //Add my code here
);
c.runCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to run a task.

If you use Java 1.5 or more, take a look at java.util.concurrent package.

You'll find interfaces such as ExecutorService and Runnable which could help.

You would create instances of such Runnable classes to achieve what you want, with your "runCode" function being ExecutorService.execute()

Answer (score 0):

You should define that code in a method inside your class and then call it whenever is neccessary. For example:

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(){ ... }

    public void runCode(){
        // Your code goes here
    }

}
```

Then you can access your code as: `c.runCode();`

Comment: Well the point of having a varible is to get rid of the class alltogether

Comment: But the class must already exist for the variable to be declared.  What do you want to use this for?

Comment: As Brian said, you can't instantiate `c` without `MyClass` existing. What is your motivation behind getting rid of `MyClass`? Are you trying to do something like write code at runtime?

Comment: It's for collision testing for entities in a small engine my friend and I are creating. we have the entity bot, and then you create Varibles of bot to add them to the screen.

Comment: and we want the entities to do specific things (eg, talk to you, run away) and we don't want to write class after class

Comment: Frankly, I think you're making your code more complex and less readable if you're trying to avoid making more classes. If I were tackling a similar issue, I would create a super class (maybe even an abstract class if child classes have a lot of shared functionality) and derive all my child classes from there. At that point, you could also hold these instances in common containers, such as `List<? extends SuperClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, if your variable type is, like, `Queue<Runnable>`, or internally has a `Queue<Runnable>`, then sure.  You just add a new `Runnable` to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpenetrating your question correctly, it looks like you want to dynamically edit the source of your program while it's running? While not exactly impossible, it's extremely dangerous an unnecessary to do so.

You can avoid this with safe, proper use of control structures.

Just put the code you want to "add" inside a method:

```
//i want to add code to program
methodWithCode();

void methodWithCode(){
    // code here
}
```

or inside a conditional statement.

```
if(i_want_to_add_code){
    // code here
}
```